# If I use a for loop in python do I need to set the variable being used to count to 0 or will the for loop set it?

Tags: python

Sorry for a badly worded question there but I am basically asking if I have:

```
for i in range(0,10):
```

Do I need to set `i = 0` at a previous point or will the for loop set `i = 0`?

I am new to python coming from mainly using C and in C there was always a part of the `for` loop that set `i = 0` (or whatever).

Comment: Actually, you hardly ever need to use `for i in range(10):` as you would in C. You iterate directly over your objects, as in `for item in my_collection:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not need to set `i` to anything beforehand.

In python you do not need to pre-declare variables. The `for` loop simply assigns the next value from the `range()` to `i` in each iteration of the loop.

Where in C you needed a `for` loop to generate indices into an array, in python you normally just loop over the sequence *directly*:

```
for element in somelist:
    # do something with element
```

rather than

```
for i in range(len(somelist)):
    element = somelist[i]
```

Comment: Nice - this is actually exactly what I am looking to use it for. Thanks.

Comment: I have lists with multiple columns, I want to compare the value of the first column to the element of another list. Is there a way to specify the column I want to use?

Comment: Sure; looping over a list of lists sets `element` to each sublist; just use indexing: `element[1]` for the second column.

Comment: So if i have a list with 3 sublists eg somelist= [[],[],[]] then to inspect the 3rd row of the second column I want somelist[1[3]] (sorry this is slightly off on a tangent but I'd rather figure it out now than open a whole new question)

Comment: No, don't nest the indices. `somelist[1][3]` is what you want. Indexing the outer list (`somelist[1]`) gives you the *inner* list at that position, so you then index that one by adding `[3]`.

Answer (score 8):

The `for` loop in python is similar to `foreach` in other languages.  `range (0, 10)` defines a list of numbers from 0 to 10, excluding 10.  The for loop then successively sets `i` to each value in the list.  So you do not need to define or initialize `i` beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumerate()` for count the loop simply.

```
>>> for i,c in enumerate('abcde') :
...  print i,c
... 
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
```

Comment: While this wasn't directly asked, it can be a very useful information for the OP and maybe this would have been one of his next questions. So I give +0.5. As this doesn't work, it gets rounded up to a full +1.

Answer (score 1):

for is a working a bit different as you expect: it 'iterates' directly over a so-called 'iterator', instead over a variable. If you got an object or a function that supports iteration or generation, you can use the for-statement.

Range() is actually returning a sequence of numbers, which the for-statement takes. It executes its body for each of those numbers.